# Why does if statement remove the concatenated variable from the filename in bash script?

Tags: bash, if-statement, directory, concatenation, filenames

I am new to programming with bash script and have run into an issue that I unfortunately have not been able to find the answer to. I have written some code that is supposed to check whether a file exists in a directory or not. The filename is a string with an attached numeric variable. When I concatenate the variable and string using `echo` it returns the correct output. However upon applying to the `if` statement, the concatenated numeric variable `${z}` is left out of the output.

```
for ((c=$start; c<=$total; c++))
do

  echo "in loop $c";
  
  num=502;
  echo $num
  
  z=$(($num+$c));
  echo $z
  
 
  echo "CL100127346_L02_${z}_1.fq.gz"
  
  if [ -f "CL100127346_L02_${z}_1.fq.gz" ];
  then
    
    echo "CL100127346_L02_${z}_1.fq.gz" exists
  
  else

    echo "CL100127346_L02_${z}_1.fq.gz does not exist"
    continue

  fi
done
```

I am guessing this is most likely a syntax error, however I am unable to find the answer. I would greatly appreciate any help. Thank you very much.

Comment: Compare `CL100127346_L02_${z}_1.fq.gz` and `CL100127346_L02_${path}_1.fq.gz`; one time you are using `$z` and the other time you are using `$path`.

Comment: Also, `for ((c=$total; c=$start; c++))` is almost certainly wrong; it initially sets `c` to the value of `total`, then sets it to the value of `start` and if that's nonzero, runs the loop. Since it always sets `c` to `start`, and `start` never changes, the loop will either never run or run forever. The `c++` will increment `c` after each loop, but since it immediately gets set back to `start`, this has no effect. What is the loop actually supposed to do?

Comment: It probably should be `for ((c = $start; c < $total; c++))`

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net is your friend to check your code.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out the error in my for loop I have now fixed this issue and updated this post. Unfortunately it has not fixed the primary issue.